# Why would you ever need (?(R)...|...) if condition in a regex?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I was looking though some regex documentation and was confused by something.  The `(R)` condition in the context of `(?(R)...|...)` is said to be:

[perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(R)) was a little cryptic:

> (R)
>
>   Checks if the expression has been evaluated inside of recursion. Full syntax: (?(R)then|else)

[PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC24) wasn't much use:

> (?(R)               overall recursion condition

and [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) had nothing to say about it.

Is this condition to say if the subroutine stack is more than 1 level deep or does it mean something else?

Comment: See [this explanation](https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Preg_question_type): *if there is no subpattern named 'R', the condition is true if a recursive call to the whole pattern or any subpattern has been made*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah.  Pretty much what I got out of the perl explanation.  Exactly what is their definition of recursion?  The same subroutine being called in the call stack?  So, there is a search to see that the current subroutine has been called more than once?  Or is it simpler, in that they just test to see if the stack depth is > 1?  I only ask because perl states for the `?(Rn)` and `?(Rname)` that it only goes back one call.

Comment: That is what it is all about I think. `R` itself checks if the whole pattern was recursed, `Rn`/`Rname` checks if a specific group pattern was recursed, and the result of the check is boolean, either True if recursion took place, or False otherwise.

Comment: Yeah. I think I'm hung up about their use of the word recursion. To me, it would be that a section is calling itself, rather than a section is calling any other section. ($a) = "abc" =~ /((?<a>(?(R)b|a))(?&a))/; print $a outputs ab, so it is just checking if the stack depth is > 0.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But the check is shallow meaning only the current level of recursion is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this explanation](https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Preg_question_type):

> if there is no subpattern named 'R', the condition is true if a recursive call to the whole pattern or any subpattern has been made

This implies that `(?(R)` condition checks if the whole pattern was recursed *at least once*, and the result of the check is boolean, either *True* if recursion took place, or *False* otherwise.

If you need to check some examples, see https://github.com/PhilipHazel/pcre2/blob/587b94277b50ababde2380b5877c93e36ca65db8/src/pcre2_jit_test.c.